# 2D array of dictionaries - copying

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, copy

Lets tell i've got 2D array of dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<int, string>[,] mat = new Dictionary<int, string>[3, 5]
{
  { new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>() },
  { new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>() },
  { new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>() },
  { new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>() },           
  { new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>(), new Dictionary<int, string>() }
}
```

And i need to **copy** this to another. I tried all ways.
Something like:

```
matNew = mat;
```

But still when i change the first one, ,it automatically change the second one.
I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: One changes and so does the other, so you are saying you want a deep copy instead?

Comment: Array is a reference type; "mat" is just a reference to the instance, and "matNew = mat" copies the reference, not the actual array. Are you trying to create a copy of the array, or a copy of the array AND all of the Dictionaries in it?

Comment: I assume the dimensions should be `[5, 3]`, not `[3, 5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want a deep copy?

```
var matNew = new Dictionary<int, string>[mat.GetLength(0), mat.GetLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); ++j)
        matNew[i, j] = new Dictionary<int, string>(mat[i, j]);
```

The [`Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz.aspx) constructor copies all elements from the specified dictionary, and is probably the fastest way of performing a shallow clone of an existing dictionary. This is suitable for your case, since your keys and values are both immutable (`int` and `string`).